# Can I claim that $\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n=\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n^++\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n^- $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I motivate the following.

I'm writing a proof for that if a seris $\sum a _n $ *converges conditionally* then the series consisting of its negative terms and the series consisting of its positive terms must both diverge. And my proof hinge of the following:

I separete the positive terms from the negative by writing $a _n ^+=(a _n + |a _n |)/2 $ and $a _n ^- = (a _n - |a _n |)/2 $

**Then how can I motivate that I can write**

$$\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n=\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n^++\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n^-   $$

Since from here I can argue that both series on the right must diverge, but I'm not sure I'm correct to claim the equality between the both sides.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think grouping and rearranging terms of an infinite sum has been proven to not produce acceptable results (see the proof of $\sum_0 ^{\infty} {(-1)^n} = 0$ for example). There must be another more rigorous way to solve this.

Comment: @patatahooligan But it _is_ valid if the series converges absolutely. So, we know that "the RHS sums converge" $\Rightarrow$ "the LHS converges absolutely or diverges," but I'm not entirely sure about the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a seris $\sum a _n $ *converges absolutelly* then the series consisting of its negative terms and the series consisting of its positive terms must both diverge.

Since $a _n ^+=\frac{(a _n + |a _n |)}{2} \le \frac{(|a _n| + |a _n |)}{2}=|a_n|$, then $\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n^+ $ converges.

It is easy to see that $\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n^- $ also converges.

Therefore $$\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n=\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n^++\sum _n ^{\infty }a _n^-   $$

Comment: You mean "converge" in your first paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

You can write $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n^++a_n^-),$$
but writing what you did seems a bit of a stretch. You can argue, however, that if both "half sums" converge, then the full sum will also converge.

I do not see how that means *both* series must diverge.

Comment: That's not true. For $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k$, we have $a_n^+=n$, $a_n^-=-n$. So the LHS in your equation gives $\ln(2)$ but the RHS gives zero. _But_, in that equation we know that "the OP's RHS diverges" $\Rightarrow$ "the OP's LHS converges conditionally or diverges." We want to know if this is always the case.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Actually, one of $a_n^-, a_n^+$ is always zero, so no, you do not have $a_n^+=n, a_n^-=-n$.

Comment: Right, sorry. You have $\{a_n^-\}_0^\infty=\{0,1,0,2,0,3,\dots\}$ and similarly for $a_n^+$. So $a_n=a_n^++a_n^-$, and your equation is correct. I apologize.

Comment: @columbus8myhw No need to apologize, we all make mistakes.

Comment: I actually meant $\{0,2,0,4,\dots\}$, come to think of it. EDIT: My original sum was meant to be the $\ln2$ series - I meant the reciprocals. Agh.

Comment: @columbus8myhw In fact $a_n^+ = (1,0,1,0,\dots)$ and $a_n^- = (0,-1,0,-1,\dots)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ be a conditionally convergent series, so $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges but $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|a_{n}\right|$ diverges.

Since the term-by-term sum or difference of two series is divergent

if one series converges and the other diverges, it follows that

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}^{+}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_n+\left|a_n\right|\right)$  $\;$ and $\;\;$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}^{-}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_n-\left|a_n\right|\right)$ $\;\;$ both diverge.

Answer (score 1):

To be rigorous, it might be easier to do things via partial sums. 
Let $S_n = \sum_{m=1}^n a_m$, let $T_n = \sum_{m=1}^n a_m^+$, and let $U_n = \sum_{m=1}^n a_m^-$.

The statement that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges is equivalent to the statement that 
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$ exists and is finite. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^+$ also
converges, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} T_n$ exists and is finite, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (2T_n - S_n)$ exists and is finite.

But $2a_n^+ - a_n = 2a_n^+ - a_n^+ + a_n^- = a_n^+ + a_n^- = |a_n|$. Hence $2T_n - S_n = \sum_{m=1}^n |a_m|$.
So the statement that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (2T_n - S_n)$ exists and is finite means that the series converges absolutely. Hence if both $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^+$ converge, the series converges absolutely.

A similar argument can be used if If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^-$ converges. So if the series converges conditionally, neither $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^+$ nor $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^-$ can converge.... since in either case the result would be that your series converges absolutely, which doesn't occur under conditional convergence.